# Extending search in backend orders list for product items by id or by sku

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, orders

Im trying to use the following code from [Search by order item SKU or ID in Woocommerce Orders Admin page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28063920/search-by-order-item-sku-or-id-in-woocommerce-orders-admin-page) to enable searching woocommerce orders by sky and id, sku being the important part for me.

```
   add_filter( 'woocommerce_shop_order_search_fields', function ($search_fields ) {
    $posts = get_posts(array('post_type' => 'shop_order'));

    foreach ($posts as $post) {
        $order_id = $post->ID;
        $order = new WC_Order($order_id);
        $items = $order->get_items();

        foreach($items as $item) {
            $product_id = $item['product_id'];
            $search_sku = get_post_meta($product_id, "_sku", true);
            add_post_meta($order_id, "_product_sku", $sku);
            add_post_meta($order_id, "_product_id", $product_id);
        }
    }

    return array_merge($search_fields, array('_product_sku', '_product_id'));
});
```

When I add this to my functions.php I get the following errors:

```
Array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'woocommerce_shop_order_search_order_total' not found or invalid function name in /var/sites/s/silverfx.co.uk/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php on line 235

Warning: array_merge(): Argument #1 is not an array in /var/sites/s/silverfx.co.uk/public_html/wp-content/themes/SilverFx-Theme/functions.php on line 156

Warning: array_map(): Argument #2 should be an array in /var/sites/s/silverfx.co.uk/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/admin/class-wc-admin-post-types.php on line 1533

Warning: array_map(): Argument #2 should be an array in /var/sites/s/silverfx.co.uk/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/admin/class-wc-admin-post-types.php on line 1557

Warning: implode(): Invalid arguments passed in /var/sites/s/silverfx.co.uk/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/admin/class-wc-admin-post-types.php on line 1557
```

Im making the assumption that since this is about 1 year old and woocommerce have gone through some big changes in that time, this code is needs updating in someway however i am not experienced enough with woocommerce to recognise what is wrong.

If anyonce out there is able to just confirm I am on the correct path or offer guidence / suggestions as to what I might need to do that would be great.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks to @LoicTheAztez the issue is resolved, his first edit resolved the problem, my ability to implement it correctly seems to have been the issue :)

Comment: @LoicTheAztez maybe my copy and paste skill arnt so bad after all, it was your update!! thanks again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **Updated:** compatibility with WooCommerce 3+

While `woocommerce_shop_order_search_fields` filter hook extend search in backend orders list, you need to add some post_meta fields for order item(s) search based on id or sku.

The author have **made a mistake in *product sku* `add_post_meta()`**. You need to replace undefined **`$sku`** variable by **`$search_sku`** instead, *I think*.

**Update:** after some thinking and some search around wordpress functions used in this code snippet, I think i have got the solution.

Here is the updated code related [to add_post_meta() function](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_post_meta) issue:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_shop_order_search_fields', function ($search_fields ) {
    $orders = get_posts( array( 'post_type' => 'shop_order' ) );

    foreach ($orders as $order_post) {
        $order_id = $order_post->ID;
        $order = new WC_Order($order_id);
        $items = $order->get_items();

        foreach( $order->get_items() as $item_id => $item_values ) {
            if ( version_compare( WC_VERSION, '3.0', '<' ) ) {
                $product_id = $item_values['product_id'];
            } else {
                $product_id = $item_values->get_product_id();
            }
            $search_sku = get_post_meta($product_id, "_sku", true);
            add_post_meta($order_id, "_product_id", $product_id, true); //  <= ## Here ##
            add_post_meta($order_id, "_product_sku", $search_sku, true); // <= ## Here ##
        }
    }
    return array_merge($search_fields, array('_product_id', '_product_sku'));
} );
```

There is a missing optional argument, that specify that the **value** is not an array, when set to `true`.

This should work now.

Reference:

- [Search by order item SKU or ID in Woocommerce Orders Admin page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28063920/search-by-order-item-sku-or-id-in-woocommerce-orders-admin-page/28718266#28718266)
- https: [WP codex add_post_meta()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_post_meta)

Comment: The code does not work anymore. No orders found when I am trying to search by ID or SKU.

Answer (score 0):

You can do an additinal query in the search result filter. This code will also search the product meta like attributes etc.

```
function woocommerce_shop_order_search_results_with_product_info( $order_ids, $term, $search_fields ) {
global $wpdb;

if ( ! empty( $search_fields ) ) {
    $order_ids = array_unique(
        array_merge(
            $order_ids,
            $wpdb->get_col(
                $wpdb->prepare(
                    "SELECT DISTINCT order_id
                            FROM kn_woocommerce_order_items
                            RIGHT JOIN (
                                SELECT kn_woocommerce_order_itemmeta.order_item_id, kn_postmeta.meta_value
                                FROM kn_woocommerce_order_itemmeta 
                                LEFT JOIN kn_postmeta ON kn_woocommerce_order_itemmeta.meta_value = kn_postmeta.post_id
                                WHERE kn_woocommerce_order_itemmeta.meta_key = '_product_id' AND kn_postmeta.meta_value LIKE %s
                            ) AS order_items ON order_items.order_item_id = kn_woocommerce_order_items.order_item_id",
                    '%' . $wpdb->esc_like( wc_clean( $term ) ) . '%'
                )
            )
        )
    );
}

    return $order_ids; 
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_shop_order_search_results', 'woocommerce_shop_order_search_results_with_product_info', 999, 3 );
```