# WooCommerce: Filter Admin orders by product custom taxonomy

Tags: woocommerce, taxonomy

I have the products with custom taxonomy, season. For example, there is an order with product from season 19fw, 20fw and so on. So I'd like to filter the order based on custom taxonomy, season.
Found following code in here. It shows a dropdown menu but it didn't work. Any help would be appreciated.

```
// Custom function where metakeys / labels pairs are defined
function get_product_attribute_size_terms(){
$taxonomy = 'season';
$options  = array();

foreach ( get_terms( array('taxonomy' => 'season' ) ) as $term ) {
    $options[$term->slug] = $term->name;
}
return $options;
}

// Add a dropdown to filter orders by variations size
add_action( 'restrict_manage_posts', 'display_admin_shop_order_by_meta_filter' );
function display_admin_shop_order_by_meta_filter(){
global $pagenow, $typenow;

if( 'shop_order' === $typenow && 'edit.php' === $pagenow ) {
    $domain    = 'woocommerce';
    $filter_id = 'by_season';
    $current   = isset($_GET[$filter_id])? $_GET[$filter_id] : '';

    echo '<select name="'.$filter_id.'">
    <option value="">' . __('Filter by Season…', $domain) . '</option>';

    $options = get_product_attribute_size_terms();

    foreach ( $options as $key => $label ) {
        printf( '<option value="%s"%s>%s</option>', $key,
            $key === $current ? '" selected="selected"' : '', $label );
    }
    echo '</select>';
   }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [WooCommerce: Filter Admin orders by product attribute term](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66250546/woocommerce-filter-admin-orders-by-product-attribute-term)

Comment: taxonomy if its attribute should start with pa_ so pa_season.

Comment: Yes, that's the code I wrote in here. pa_season doesn;'t work either. If it was used, there is a blank in dropdown menu.